# Simple MDX having aggregated values grouped by 2 dimensions

Tags: mdx

I am very new to MDX, and for starters I downloaded a plugin for excel 0 OLAPPivotGrid Extensions. I use this to generate reports, copy the MDX and use that bound to grid.

However, I need to create other simple queries, but am finding problems creating something that can be done easily by SQL. For instance, if I had this SQL query how would I get around with MDX?

Select Day, ProductType, sum(amount), sum(amount2)
Where day => 20120101 and day < 20120201
Group by Day,ProductType

Now in my case, for instance, Day and product type are 2 different dimensions, and when doing this type of MDX query I am getting "Two sets specified in the  function have different dimensionality."

Can anyone help me out please?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by using CrossJoin, and DrilldownLevel for both the dimensions. Then I used filters, in the [From] part of the MDX query.